# How can I stop duplicate array in my React - using infinite scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, infinite-scroll

I have tried to do an infinite scroll by using [React-Infinite-Scroll-Component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component)

Everything is working perfectly as I think, but the problem is whenever I change the Genres, or press F5 to reload the page, or somehow, the scrollbar is always at the very bottom, I did try to fix it with `window.scrollTo(0,0)` but it's still not working.

Or somehow do I mess up the code because I tried to work around it very hard, but I don't think I execute it well enough.

The code is very ***long*** but here's a brief explanation of what I'm trying to do in it.

I received a slug which defined as a `genre` with `useParams`, for example `action` or `adventure`, then I set it as a state `genreAnime`, then I check if it's the same genre, it'll do the infinite load with `concat array` and increase the page up to 1 for the next load, else I'll set a new `array` and initial the page back to 1 or else it'll keep merging with an old array of previous `genre`. The `totalPage` is set to 91, whenever it renders for the second time it'll automatically get the latest `totalPage` and set it back, so it's safe to go.

The `translateGenre` is just for translating the genre into text, so please don't bother it.

But then whenever I refresh (F5) or whenever I browse for a bit, then I change the genre, it'll get a duplicate of the same `first array` (due to warning and I see it has 2 same items). Due to the scrollbar of mine always staying at the "end" or at the `default` value of ***React-Infinite-Scroll-Component***, which is 0.8, it means when users come below 80% of the total height, it'll trigger the `next` function of `Infinite-Scroll-Component`

Here's my code:

```
function AnimeGenre({ instance }) {
    const { genre } = useParams()

    const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken
    const source = CancelToken.source()

    const [animeList, setAnimeList] = useState([])
    const [genreAnime, setGenreAnime] = useState("")
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
    const [totalPage, setTotalPage] = useState(91)
    const [translateGenreAnime, setTranslateGenreAnime] = useState("")

    const getList = async () => {
        await instance
            .get(`/anime/${genre}?page=${page}`, {
                cancelToken: source.token,
            })
            .then((response) => {
                const newPage = page + 1
                setPage(newPage)
                const newList = response.data.data.map((anime) => ({
                    slug: anime.slug,
                    thumbnail: anime.thumbnail,
                    name: anime.name,
                    views: anime.views,
                }))
                setTotalPage(response.data.pagination.totalPage)
                setAnimeList((prev) => {
                    return [...new Set([...prev, ...newList])]
                })
            })
            .catch((thrown) => {
                if (axios.isCancel(thrown)) return
            })
    }    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (genre === genreAnime) {
            getList()
            translateGenre()
        } else {
            window.onbeforeunload = function () {
              window.scrollTo(0, 0)
             }
            window.scrollTo({
                top: 0,
            })
            setPage(1)
            setAnimeList([])
            setGenreAnime(genre)
        }

        return () => {
            source.cancel()
        }
    }, [genreAnime, genre])

    const translateGenre = () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < GENRES.length; i++) {
            if (genreAnime == GENRES[i].slug) {
                setTranslateGenreAnime(GENRES[i].name)
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <h1>ANIME {translateGenreAnime}</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="anime-list">
                <InfiniteScroll
                    initialScrollY={0}
                    style={{ overflow: "none" }}
                    dataLength={animeList.length}
                    next={getList}
                    hasMore={page === totalPage ? false : true}
                    loader={
                        <Row xs={1} sm={2} md={3} lg={4}>
                            {[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11].map((skeleton) => (
                                <Col key={skeleton}>
                                    <Card>
                                        <Card.Body style={{ maxHeight: "100%" }}>
                                            <Skeleton
                                                variant="rectangular"
                                                width="100%"
                                                height="192px"
                                                animation="wave"
                                                sx={{ bgcolor: "grey.900" }}
                                            />

                                            <Skeleton
                                                variant="text"
                                                animation="wave"
                                                sx={{ bgcolor: "grey.900" }}
                                            />
                                        </Card.Body>
                                    </Card>
                                </Col>
                            ))}
                        </Row>
                    }
                    endMessage={<h4>NO MORE THINGS TO LOAD</h4>}
                >
                    <Row xs={1} sm={2} md={3} lg={4}>
                        {animeList.map((anime) => (
                            <Col key={anime.slug}>
                                <Card>
                                    <div className="card-container">
                                        <Card.Img
                                            variant="top"
                                            src={anime.thumbnail}
                                            fluid="true"
                                        />
                                        <div className="overlay-card">
                                            <a className="icon">{<BsFillPlayFill size={40} />}</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <Card.Body>
                                        <Card.Title>
                                            <TextTruncate
                                                line={2}
                                                element="span"
                                                truncateText="…"
                                                text={anime?.name}
                                            />
                                        </Card.Title>
                                    </Card.Body>
                                </Card>
                                <div className="w-100"></div>
                            </Col>
                        ))}
                    </Row>
                </InfiniteScroll>
            </div>
         <>
        }
```

It's work fine whenever the `scrollbar` stay at the very top, because it won't surpass the threshold of 80% of the height.

Working one:

[image: Scrollbar on top is work]

Fail when I browse a bit and change the `GENRE`, due to the scrollbar is stay at bottom, then later on, it'll do the scrollTo(0,0). Which is not what I want, I want the opposite, it must always go to top first...

[image: Fail when change GENRE]

The second fail is when I press reload the page with F5 button. It'll somehow display very weird (the scrollbar).

[image: F5 fail]

UPDATE:

I tried to disable `smooth-scrolling behavior` and set up the scroll to top into the `header` component that has the navbar, that's seem more proper way to do it, it's get my scrollbar to the top as I want whenever I clicked something in the header or refresh using F5.

But still if at the first time render, I browse the page and scroll down too fast, I'll get duplicate error due to I meet the threshold and the previous function is still being executed, if I wait for the first render to fully load, then pretty much I am fine, is there any proper way to do infinite scroll, please show me some simple way, I feel like I'm making it too compicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it right, but not so sure, it's working fine, "for now".

This is what I do.

Instead of

```
const newPage = page + 1
setPage(newPage)
```

inside the `getList` function, I split it out into another function called `scrollThreshold`

```
const scrollThreshold = () => {
    const newPage = page + 1
    setPage(newPage)
}
```

and I set

```
const PAGE_NUMBER = 1
```

outside of the component (or else I think I should use `useRef` or just leave it be, just in case)

then at the `useEffect`, I implement 1 more dependencies, it's `page` state, whenever the I get new `page` or `page` state change, or `genre` change, it'll run the `useEffect` again.

then at the `InfiniteScroll` component, I slightly change it from

```
<InfiniteScroll>
...
next={getList}
...
</InfiniteScroll>
```

into

```
<InfiniteScroll>
...
next={getList && scrollThreshold}
...
</InfiniteScroll>
```

So whenever I scroll down, it'll trigger both getList and scrollThreshold, by being separated, it won't clump together like my first code. And so far it's working, I don't know if this is good or not.